# NPM run build: missing script: "build"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, build, digital-ocean

Ive been trying to deploy my React Node.js app to DigitalOcean. I am getting npm error "missing script: build". I have included a build script in my package.js folder. Why is it saying its not included?

```js
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
   "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Comment: Does it work when you execute `npm run build` ?

Comment: No it has the same npm error! missing script: build

Comment: Does `react-scripts build` work then ?

Comment: It returns Command not found: react-scripts. I entered "react-scripts build"

Comment: Well I think `react-scripts` isn't installed. It should be in the dependencies of package.json

Comment: I do have  "react-scripts": "^3.4.4", in the dependencies.